# How does flying at high altitude affect the taste of wine?

Tags: air-travel, food-and-drink, factoids, alcohol

I can appreciate a wine offered during a flight. It is not uncommon to be offered a selection of wines, [but since pressurised cabins affect your taste](http://www.theatlantic.com/health/archive/2014/05/the-evolution-of-airplane-food/371076/), does it make sense? Can you assume that your personal preferences on the ground remain the same at high altitude? Is there any research on how your taste changes?

Comment: I'm really not convinced that this question is travel-related...

Comment: Given the general quality(or the lack thereof) if wine on an airplane... it may not be your taste...

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/19808/444

Comment: It is really relative. Most people are used to the cabin have lower-pressure but this is not always the case. When landing in Quito for example, the pressure always drops.

Answer (score 4):

Taste is dulled at altitude, which is one reason airline food tends to have far more salt, garlic, and other strong flavors.  You are correct that you can't assume that your preferences in the air will be identical to on the ground.  You may find that red wines taste better in the air, for example.  The best advice is to try different flavors and see what you like in the environment.  You can also try to book flights on the B787 ("Dreamliner") which has higher air pressure (lower cabin altitude) and higher humidity.